# Convergence of gradient descent - derivation help

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

I am following along some old lectures notes that I found online ([source](https://people.kth.se/~alepro/DistriOptCourse/lecture1.pdf)) and I was hoping someone could provide some insight into a bound regarding gradient descent.

The goal is to solve $\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)$.

One approach is to use gradient descent to update the variable as (using initial point $x_0$)

\begin{align}
x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha_k\nabla f(x_k),\,\alpha_k>0.
\end{align}

For all $k\ge1$, we have (this is what I don't understand, see slide 9)
\begin{align}
f(x_k) - f^* \le \frac{\|x_0-x^*\|^2 + \sum_{t=0}^{k-1}\alpha_t^2\|\nabla f(x_t)\|^2}{2\sum_{t=0}^{k-1}\alpha_t}
\end{align}

Does anyone see where the above bound could have possibly come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that $f$ is convex (based on the notes). For any $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ we have, at iteration $k$,

$$\begin{align}\|x_{k+1}-x\|^2 & =  \|x_{k} - \alpha_k\nabla f(x_k) - x\|^2  \\ 
& =   \|x_{k} - x\|^2 - 2 \alpha_k\nabla f(x_k)^T (x_k - x) + \alpha_k^2 \|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2.  \end{align}$$

On the other hand, rearranging the gradient's inequality for convex functions at $x_k$, we have
$$-\nabla f(x_k)^T (x_k - x) \leq f(x)-f(x_k),$$
(cf. [Boyd's book](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), p. 69, eq. 3.2) so we can bound the last equality:
$$\begin{align}\|x_{k+1}-x\|^2 & \leq    \|x_{k} - x\|^2 + 2 \alpha_k (f(x) - f(x_k)) + \alpha_k^2 \|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2.  \end{align}$$
Rearranging once more, we get 
$$2 \alpha_k (f(x_k) - f(x)) \leq    \|x_{k} - x\|^2 - \|x_{k+1}-x\|^2 + \alpha_k^2 \|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2. $$
Now sum over $t$:
$$2\sum_{t=0}^k \alpha_t (f(x_t) - f(x)) \leq    \|x_{0} - x\|^2 - \|x_{k+1}-x\|^2 + \sum_{t=0}^k\alpha_t^2 \|\nabla f(x_t)\|^2.$$
To get the desired bound, notice that the middle term can be dropped from the RHS and that $f(x_k)$ is the smallest of the $f(x_t)$, so you can replace it in the LHS. Finally, divide by $2\sum _{t=0}^k \alpha_t$ to obtain

\begin{align}
f(x_k) - f(x) \le \frac{\|x_0-x\|^2 + \sum_{t=0}^{k}\alpha_t^2\|\nabla f(x_t)\|^2}{2\sum_{t=0}^{k}\alpha_t}.
\end{align}

Comment: How do we know that $f(x_k)$ is the smallest of the $f(x_t)$'s? Hopefully this post isn't too far back to get an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rogerG I supposed there that the sequence $f(x_k)$ was nonincreasing. That should be true for small enough parameters $\alpha_k$, as noted in slides 7 and 8 in your link.